# Hyperbolic Geometry: Representation of the metric in a chart

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{R}^{1,n}$ denote Lorentzian $n$-space, i.e., $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the Lorentzian inner product $$\langle x,y \rangle = - x_0 y_0 + x_1 y_1 + \cdots + x_n y_n.$$

Define $\mathbb{H}^n : = \left \{ \xi \in \mathbb{R}^{1,n} : \langle \xi, \xi \rangle = -1, \ \xi_0 > 0 \right \}$ to be hyperbolic $n$-space. I have been battling with the following seemingly standard/trivial exercises in Jöst's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* and have had little success:

5) Show that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ induces a Riemannian metric on the tangent spaces $T_p \mathbb{H}^n \subset T_p \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ for $p \in \mathbb{H}^n$.

6) Let $s = (-1, 0, ..., 0) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and define $$f(x) = s - \frac{2(x-s)}{\langle x-s, x-s \rangle}.$$ Show that $f : \mathbb{H}^n \longrightarrow \{ \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n : | \xi | < 1 \}$ is a diffeomorphism, and that in this chart, the metric assumes the form $$\frac{4}{(1 - | \xi |^2)^2} d\xi_i \otimes d\xi_i.$$

*Thoughts/Progress:*

The fact that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ defines an inner product is clear, but I cannot convince myself that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is positive definite. For Q6., I am aware that a similar question has been posted on here, but the solution is not clear to me.

*Note that I do not want answers to these problems, just guidance.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $5)$ I have a trick so I don't know how to give a hint about this solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with differential forms and their use in differential geometry? If so, I can give some hints.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am familiar with differential forms. I am just new to the hyperbolic material.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. The check that the induced metric on the orthogonal complement of $\xi$ is positive-definite is just basic linear algebra. If you want to see an easy moving-frames computation that this space has constant curvature $-1$, I'll show you that ... :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I would appreciate that if you have the time. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing. If my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882924/what-is-the-curvature-form-omega-associated-with-the-levi-civita-connection-f/2883972#2883972) makes sense to you, I'll show you how things get modified in the $O(n,1)$ case. Just post a separate question.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks Ted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will prove $5)$. As differential manifold, $\mathbb{H}^n$ is a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ so we can identify tangent vectors in $\mathbb{H}^n$ as velocities of differentiable curves in $\mathbb{H}^n$. Take a point $p=(p_0,\ldots,p_n)$ in $\mathbb{H}^n$ and a differentiable curve $\sigma : (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to \mathbb{H}^n$ such that $\sigma(0)=p$. Write the coordinates of $\sigma$ as $\sigma_0,\ldots,\sigma_n$ and let $v_i=\frac{d\sigma_i}{dt}(0)$ for every $i$. So we want to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^2>v_0^2$.

We have that $\langle \sigma(t),\sigma(t) \rangle =-1$ for every $t$. So in particular at $0$ we have that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^np_i^2 = p_0^2-1
$$

On the other hand, by the product rule for derivatives we have that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^nv_ip_i = v_0p_0
$$

So, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the first equation, it follows that

$$
v_0^2p_0^2=\bigg{(}\sum_{i=1}^nv_ip_i\bigg{)}^2\leq \bigg{(}\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^2\bigg{)} \bigg{(}\sum_{i=1}^np_i^2\bigg{)} = \bigg{(}\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^2\bigg{)} \bigg{(}p_0^2-1\bigg{)} < \bigg{(}\sum_{i=1}^nv_i^2\bigg{)} p_0^2
$$

We know that $p_0>0$ by definition of $\mathbb{H}^n$ so the proposition follows.

EDIT: Sketch of $6)$. Let $\mathbb{D}^n=\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n:|\xi|<1\}$. Note that $f:\mathbb{H}^n\to\mathbb{D}^n$ is defined by the formula
$$
f(x_0,\ldots,x_n)=\bigg{(}\frac{x_1}{1+x_0},\ldots,\frac{x_n}{1+x_0}\bigg{)}
$$

and it is differentiable. The inverse $f^{-1}:\mathbb{D}^n\to\mathbb{H}^n$, defined by the formula

$$
f^{-1}(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)=\bigg{(}\frac{1+|\xi|^2}{1-|\xi|^2},\frac{2\xi_1}{1-|\xi|^2},\ldots,\frac{2\xi_n}{1-|\xi|^2}\bigg{)},
$$

is differentiable so $f$ is a diffeomorphism. Prove that the pullback by $f^{-1}$ of the metric defined in $\mathbb{H}^n$ is equal to the metric given on $\mathbb{D}^n$, that is

$$
\bigg{\langle} \frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial \xi_i}(\xi),\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial\xi_j}(\xi) \bigg{\rangle} = \frac{4\delta_{ij}}{(1-|\xi|^2)^2}
$$

for every $i,j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and every $\xi\in\mathbb{D}^n$.

Note that $6)$ implies $5)$ because the pullback by a diffeomorphism of a riemannian metric is a riemannian metric.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I very much appreciate this.

Comment: You are welcome! Please select my answer as the "accepted" answer if it works for you. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Very pleased with this answer, thanks again.